# How to trigger Cloud Run from Global EventArc using pub sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run, event-arc

I have a cloudrun service deployed in asia-south1 region and would like to trigger it from eventarc when a message is published in pubsub.

However asia-south1 doesn't have eventarc, so I decided to create event arc trigger as location=global.

Below see below command.

```
    gcloud eventarc triggers create pubsub-trigger-new-auction-notification \
    --location=global \
    --destination-run-service=notification \
    --destination-run-path=/notify/bidder/auction \
    --destination-run-region=asia-south1 \
    --event-filters="type=google.cloud.pubsub.topic.v1.messagePublished" \
    --transport-topic=projects/<my-project_id>/topics/newauction-notify \
    --service-account=cloud-run-pubsub-invoker@<my-project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

However it fails with below error mentioning that type should be **google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written**

```
ERROR: (gcloud.eventarc.triggers.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request was invalid: [INVALID_ARGUMENT] The request was invalid: invalid value for attribute 'type' in trigger.event_filters: only type "google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written" is allowed in global location
```

When I try to create trigger with **google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written**
It fail with missing service name error. Please see below

```
ERROR: (gcloud.eventarc.triggers.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request was invalid: [INVALID_ARGUMENT] The request was invalid: missing required attribute "serviceName" in trigger.event_filters
```

I could not seem to find any documentation which mentions about global trigger with pubsub and cloud run.
Can somebody please help me to understand how to link a pubsub based event trigger to cloud run when event arc location is global or point me to right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the location that you want where eventarc is supported. The "issue" that you will have is you will pay for the inter-region traffic. that's all.

---

As workaround, you need to know how work EventArc. it create, under the hood (but you can see that in your project) a pubsub push subscription to call your Cloud Run service at the specified URL.

You can create manually this push subscription and wait for an eventarc availability in your region.

Comment: Thanks guillaume blaquiere. Creating trigger in another region certainly helped. 

I misunderstood documentation and thought global should be used for eventarc trigger if destination run region doesn't support event arc.

I previously looked for push subscription, If I am not wrong, that requires my cloud run service to be up always to receive push event from pubsub., which I am trying to avoid currently.

Comment: As I said, EventArc create a PubSub subscription. Therefore if the Cloud Run service doesn't exist, a HTTP 404 error code is received by PubSub subscription. The message isn't acknowledged and is kept and retried up to 7 days. After, the message is deleted. Standard pubSub behavior.