# Using Eventarc to Trigger Google Cloud Functions on BigQuery Table Insert

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, etl

I am trying to leverage Google Cloud Functions to run whenever I run an insert on a table within a specific dataset in my GCP project. From what I've seen from other stackoverflow [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792976/trigger-cloud-function-when-new-data-in-bigquery),  I know it is possible to use Eventarc (2nd Gen) to listen to cloud events and trigger Cloud Functions. From looking at my BigQuery logs, I think what I want is for the Cloud Function to trigger when the logs equal:

> protoPayload.methodName:"google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob"
> resource.labels.dataset_id:"the_specific_dataset"

However, after attempting to follow multiple guides, I'm hitting perplexing errors in cloud shell. Sources I've already tried to use: [Google Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-events#0) and [This Blogpost](https://atamel.dev/posts/2021/06-08_bigquery-jobs-notifier/).

**What I Ran**

- in CloudShell, I enabled everything to run it

```html
gcloud config set project org-internal
PROJECT_ID=org-internal
gcloud services enable run.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable eventarc.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable logging.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable cloudbuild.googleapis.com
REGION=us-central1
gcloud config set run/region $REGION
gcloud config set run/platform managed
gcloud config set eventarc/location $REGION
```

- Then I configured my service account in CloudShell to have the roles eventarc.eventReceiver / pubsub publisher

> PROJECT_NUMBER=$(gcloud projects describe $PROJECT_ID
> --format='value(projectNumber)')
>
> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID 
> --member serviceAccount:$PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com 
> --role roles/eventarc.eventReceiver

- Then I deployed to CloudRun

> SERVICE_NAME=hello gcloud run deploy $SERVICE_NAME \
> --image=gcr.io/cloudrun/hello \   --allow-unauthenticated

- I was able to successfully create a trigger for cloud pub/sub. Ran without issue. However, when I tried to apply the event filters specific to table inserts, I ran into issue after issue. Here's what I tried with the errors

```html
gcloud eventarc triggers create $TRIGGER_NAME   --destination-run-service=$SERVICE_NAME   --destination-run-region=$REGION   --event-filters="serviceName=bigquery.googleapis.com" --event-filters="protoPayload.methodName:google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob" --event-filters="resource.labels.dataset_id:the_specific_dataset"
```

The error: ERROR: (gcloud.eventarc.triggers.create) argument --event-filters: Bad syntax for dict arg: [protoPayload.methodName:google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob].

```html
gcloud eventarc triggers create $TRIGGER_NAME   --destination-run-service=$SERVICE_NAME   --destination-run-region=$REGION  --event-filters="type=google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written” --event-filters="serviceName=bigquery.googleapis.com" --event-filters methodName=google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob  --event-filters resource.labels.dataset_id=the_specific_dataset
```

The error: ERROR: (gcloud.eventarc.triggers.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request was invalid: invalid value for attribute 'type' in trigger.event_filters:

I tried a few other ways in formatting (e.g. with quotes and without) but nothing seems to be working. I guess my questions are -- can I filter on "resource.labels.dataset_id" and on "methodName=google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob"? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger Cloud Run from Global EventArc using pub sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68701572/how-to-trigger-cloud-run-from-global-eventarc-using-pub-sub)